# MongoDB fetching all the documents in a collection gives an empty slice of structs using mgo

Tags: database, mongodb, go, mgo

I have inserted data into mongodb in the following way

```
  {
     "_id" : ObjectId("5c80e9cc3bf127cfc80ba5dc"),
     "resp" : [
         {
             "name" : "by",
             "gender" : "synced",
             "age" : "response",
             "hobby" : "submitted",
             "mobile" : "revision"
         },
        {
            "name" : "byoooooo",
            "gender" : "sytewed",
            "age" : "se",
            "hobby" : "subed",
            "mobile" : "revissaaon"
        }
    ]
  }
```

Using this method

```
func (d *CollectDAO) Insert(responses []*models.FormData) error {
  resp := models.Responses{
      Data: responses,
  }
  err := db.C(formsCollection).Insert(resp)
  return err
}
```

This is the struct used in the insert method

```
type FormData struct {
  Name     string `csv:"name" json:"name" bson:"name"`
  Gender   string `csv:"gender" json:"gender" bson:"gender"`
  Age      string `csv:"age" json:"age" bson:"age"`
  Hobby    string `csv:"hobby" json:"hobby" bson:"hobby"`
  MobileNo string `csv:"mobile" json:"mobile" bson:"mobile"`
}
```

The handler reads sample csv data from a file. This is the csv data

```
name,gender,age,hobby,mobile
by,synced,response,submitted,revision
byoooooo,sytewed,se,subed,revissaaon
```

And then inserts that into mongo

When querying all the documents of my collection I get an empty response

```
func (d *CollectDAO) FindAll() (models.Responses, error) {
    var responses []models.Responses
    err := db.C(formsCollection).Find(nil).All(&responses)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Printf("all docs %v\n", responses)

    return responses, err
}
```

When I try to log the value of the struct I get an empty struct. This is the responses struct that I am using at the end to put the slice of response in.

```
type Responses struct {
  Data []*FormData `json:"response"`
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I just need to implement a handler that will return all the data in a collection as a struct.

On the client side I get this error

```
unexpected end of JSON input
{ObjectIdHex("") []}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `mgo` package uses the `bson` tag to map struct fields to document fields in MongoDB.

So your `Responses` type should look something like this:

```
type Responses struct {
    Data []*FormData `json:"response" bson:"resp"`
}
```

Note that you have to save documents with this struct (with `bson` tag) to be able to fetch results into values of this type.

Comment: Hi sorry that was a copy paste error, what you have described is what I am doing, I have edited the description.

But even after using a slice of responses I get an empty slice ` [{[]}]`  and this error `unexpected end of JSON input` 
`{ObjectIdHex("") []}`

Comment: @LemmyKillmister Please post the definition of the `models.Responses` type.

Comment: models.Responses is a collection of all the form responses. The idea is that a user will fill up a form with questions, all the answers will be saved as csv. The csv file is uploaded to the server and the data is stored into mongodb. Each row of the csv file is encapsulated as the `FormData` struct and a slice of these structs are stored in the data field of `Responses` struct so Responses is nothing but the slice of all the form responses.

Comment: @LemmyKillmister Ok, see edited anser. You have to use the `bson` tag not `json` to tell how to map struct fields to document fields in MongoDB. Also note that you might have to resave your entries. If you added entries with different mapping, you might not be able to query them into this model type.

Comment: by resave do you mean inserting them again?

Comment: @LemmyKillmister Yes, do a clean start. Drop the collection, adjust your `models.Responses`, and insert the documents again. And then run the query.